# Path of current node.js c++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm writing an addon for node.js in C++ and ran into a little problem. I want to read configuration file in my module directory but unable to find it out the usual way(`__dirname`) as in C++ global object seems to be empty.

Is there a proper way of doing this or do I need to resort to hacks?

Comment: Why not just pass a path to your addon? It's easier and it allows for more flexibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__dirname` is not global, it is automatically added into the scope of the module when the module runs, otherwise every module would see one common directory name, which doesn't make sense.

`C++` modules are passed several arguments when they are initialized, just like JS modules. In the case of modules, many of those are automatically exposed. I assume you have this in your module:

```
static void init (v8::Handle<v8::Object> target) {
```

But you have access to more arguments

```
static void init (v8::Handle<v8::Object> target, v8::Handle<v8::Object> module) {
```

So you can read the filename of the module:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> filename =
        module->Get(v8::String::NewSymbol("filename")).As<v8::String>();
```

Then you can process the directory name of out of that using `path`:

```
Local<Function> require = Local<Function>::Cast(
    module->Get(String::NewSymbol("require")));

Local<String> filename = module->Get(String::NewSymbol("filename")).As<String>();

Local<Value> args[] = {String::New("path")};
Local<Object> pathModule = require->Call(Object::New(), 1, args).As<Object>();
Local<Function> dirname = pathModule->Get(String::NewSymbol("dirname")).As<Function>();

Local<Value> arg2[] = {filename};
Local<String> moduleDirname = dirname->Call(pathModule, 1, arg2).As<String>();
```